# Heat transfer area across a surface

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

This is the formula I use for heat transfer across a surface -

Q= U x A x LMTD

where , U , A and LMTD are Overall heat transfer coefficient, Heat transfer area and log mean temperature difference respectively.

Let’s say I have this exchanger (Hot oil-water exchanger) [image]

I’m having problems with understanding how to calculate the surface area.

The formula I’m using is $\pi DL$ where D is the diameter and L is the length of the exchanger.

Which diameter should I pluck in numbers to ? The larger circle or the smaller circle ? And why?

Answer (score 0):

You use this combined product of UD:  $$\frac{1}{UD}=\frac{1}{h_oD_o}+\frac{1}{h_iD_i}+\frac{1}{(k/t)D_{LM}}$$where k is the thermal conductivity of the wall, t is the wall thickness, and $D_{LM}$ is the log-mean diameter:
$$D_{LM}=\frac{(D_o-D_i)}{\ln{(D_o/D_i)}}$$